# I need to pick the cube values between 1 and 100

Tags: python, math

```
cubos = [valor**3 for valor in range(1,101)]#creates a list the cubes from 1 to 100
for cubo in cubos:#loop and create the internal values
    if cubo >= 100:#pick the values bigger then 100
        del cubo #delete them
print (cubos)#print the values lower then 100
```

why is not working
I want it to make the if work but it simply does not
it just print the list how it was with out any changes

Comment: Please read the guide lines on how to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you look at the preview pane, you'll be able to tell when your edit is about to make the formatting worse rather than better. There's a little `{}` button to help format code.

Comment: If something doesn't work, either write some toy code to check your understanding (or check it in the interpreter) or step through in pdb. You can confirm very quickly that `del`eting a variable doesn't alter the container its value came from. That is, `del cubo` is not at all like `del cubos[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Generate *all* the cubes, then pick the ones that are less than 100.

```
from itertools import takewhile, count

cubes1to100 = list(takewhile(lambda x: x <= 100, map(lambda x: x**3, count())))
```

Breaking it down:

1. `count()` produces the infinite stream of integers 0, 1, 2, ....
2. `map(lambda x: x**3, count())` produces the infinite stream of cubes 0, 1, 8, 27, 64, 125, ....
3. `takewhile(...)` produces the finite stream of cubes less than 100 by only yielding those values coming from `map` that are less or equal to 100.
4. `list`, finally, creates a list from the iterable returned by `takewhile`.

The iterators are all lazy, so `x ** 3` is only computed 6 times, as is `x <= 100`.